# $X_1,X_2$ connected. Show that $X_1\times X_2$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

> If $X_1,...,X_n$ are connected topological space, show that $X=X_1\times ...\times X_n$ is also connected.

I have the proof in front of me but I couldn't understand. It starts by claiming that:

> Let $E$ be a closed and open subset of $X$. We can assume that $E\ne\emptyset$. We must show that $E=X$. Let $z=(z_1,...,z_n)\in E$ and let $y=(y_1,...,y_n)\in X$. The intersection $E\cap (X_1\times\{z_2\}\times...\times\{z_n\})$ is a relatively open and closed subset of the coordinate slice.

Why is that intersection open and closed?

> Since $X_1$ is connected, so is the coordinate slice. So $E$ must include the entire coordinate slice.

Why must $E$ include the entire coordinate slice? I get the first part though.

Comment: Use this criterion : $X$ is connected if and only if every continous function $X \to (\mathbb Z, \mathcal T_{discrete})$ is constant.

Comment: $X$ is connected if and only if the only the only clopen set are $X$ and $\emptyset$. Therefore, if $\emptyset\neq E\neq X$ is clopen, then $X$ is not connected.

Comment: Suppose there are open sets $A,B$ s.t. $A\cup B=X$ yet $A\cap B=\emptyset $. What does that say about the $\left \{ X_{i} \right \}_{0\leq x\leq n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E\cap X_1\times \{z_2\}\times...\times \{z_n\}$ is relatively open and closed by the definition of the subspace topology: a subset $K$ of a subspace $Y\subset X$ is closed in $Y$ if and only if it's $Y\cap K'$ for some closed $K'\subset X$, and similarly for open. Now you need to check that the inclusion $X_1\to X, x\mapsto (x,z_2,...,z_n)$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, so that $E\cap X_1\times \{z_2\}\times...\times \{z_n\}$ must come from a nonempty open and closed subset of $X_1$ with the given topology, namely must be all of $X_1\times \{z_2\}\times...\times \{z_n\}$ since $X_1$ is connected.